# How to get members of groups in autocomplete light field in django

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using version 2.2.10 
I want to display users of a group in autocomplete field.
I am able to display all users in autocomplete field when I'm creating group.
But in a different scenario I need to list users of that group only when creating rosters within group users.

Existing autocomplete model:
```

```
class UserAutocomplete( autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase ):

search_fields = [ 'username', 'last_name', 'first_name',]
choices = []

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(UserAutocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.choices = User.objects.all()

def choices_for_request(self):
    print "coming in choices_for_request"
    self.choices = User.objects.all()
    return super(UserAutocomplete, self).choices_for_request()
```

```

In my form I have

```
`users = autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField('UserAutocomplete', label='Users', required=False)`
```

Now for my new form how to pass group information to UserAutocomplete so that I can modify the queryset.

I can do following without using autocomplete:
```

```
self.fields['users'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=group.users.all(),
            widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

```
But I want to use autocomplete light field. 
Let me know how to go about doing it.

Comment: you mean when you enter value for  roaster belong to a group you want auto complete returns users belongs to that group?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: i don't know about v 2.2.10 but in the latest version 3.2.1 which let you filter  result based on another field value  http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form